# Музгарка: что же это такое?

Tags: этимология

Интересно узнать происхождение слова "музгарка", может ли быть схожесть со словами "мензурка", "мазурка"??? Знаю, что Музгарка как кличка собаки, но что означает это слово?

Answer (score 1):

Музгарко - это кличка собаки из рассказа Мамина-Сибиряка «Зимовье на Студеном». Музгарко - вогульская лайка. В словаре Фасмера есть диалектное слово *м**у**зга*, означающее "лужа; мелкое пересыхающее озеро; пруд; сырая низина; степное озеро", ряз., донск. (Миртов, Шолохов), астрах.; также муз**о**г, род. п. музг**а** м. "длинная выемка", тверск. (Даль), словен. muzgа "ил, глинистая почва", "древесный сок". Имеет ли кличка что-то общее с приведенным словом - сказать трудно.

Answer (score 0):

Цитата из рассказа:

> А Музгарко, значит, мне достался... Это по речке я его и назвал, где
> вогул помирал: Музгаркой звать речку, ну, я и собаку так же назвал. И
> умный песик...

Так что, скорее всего, есть связь с диалектами, о которых говорилось в предыдущем ответе.
Мелкая пересыхающая речушка, болотистая низина и т.п.